# How can i implement the latest Google VIDEO admobs ?

Tags: android, adsense, admob

Actually the doc implementation looks unclear to me, if someone has a ready to use snippet of code, it will be welcome. please provide as much details as possible. in my case i have a Entertainment App with Google login, my user will benefit of additional features once they watch a certain number of video Ads.

Comment: Show your attempts and errors that you receive, if any,  please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you're talking about Reward Video and I prefer reward video for your case.

Take a look, having very easy integration 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video